# Creating images in for loop centred c#

Tags: c#, image

I am creating images in two for loops and hoping to have them centered as if they were one. I can not see any errors in the program but it is wrong, what have I done wrong?

```
for (int i0 = 0; i0 < 1000; i0 += 50)
{
    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < 500; i1 += 50)
    {
        Bitmap Image1 = Map_Gen.Properties.Resources.Blank;
        Image1.MakeTransparent(Color.Fuchsia);
        e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(
            Image1, 
            Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width / 2 - ((1000 / 2) + i0), 
            Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height / 2 - ((500 / 2) + i1), 
            50, 50);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the missing code most notably __where__ it runs and also tell us __what is wrong__ about the result!? Also: Please explain those hefty loops; are you __trying to tile__ the blank map? Onto the Form? Note that you are drawing the __same__ image onto the __same__ (presumably) control just at different spots!

Comment: What is your question

Comment: `I can not see any errors in the program but it is wrong, what have I done wrong? ` What result do you get instead of the expected result? What **is** the expected result? Are you trying to **tile** them? (Screenshots and Mockups would be helpful)

Comment: Do you want draw an image and then draw it repeatedly with smaller size in center of older one?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your question exactly is but I assume that you want draw an image and then draw it repeatedly with smaller size and in center of older one.

```
int Count = 2,s=2,x=0,y=0,width=image.With,height=image.Height,oldWidth=0,OldHeight=0;
for (int i= 0; i< Count; i ++)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(image,x,y,width,height);
        OldWidth= width;
        OldHeight=height;
        width/=s;
        height/=s;
        x+=(OldWidth-width)/2;
        y+=(OldHeight-height)/2;

    }
```